# Format string case on INSERT?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, insert, string-formatting

I'm inserting string values from one table into another where the string values are in all caps.

How can I alter the case of the string on INSERT such that only the first letter of every word in the string is capitalized?

Example: 'TESTING ABC' would be inserted as 'Testing Abc'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `initcap` function should do the trick:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (some_column)
SELECT INITCAP(some_other_column)
FROM   some_other_table
```